# Unable to get variable from frontend to back end with Axios.put

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using react/express/SQL

I have a simple program where user can enter data, view data and update their data. inserting and getting  data from my SQL database works fine, but when I try to update data from my database I get the following error.

Error when trying to update data

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userEvent' of undefined
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express'); // node js frontend/backend lib
const app = express() 
const mysql = require('mysql'); // DB
const cors = require('cors') //By default requests from any other origins will be restricted by the browser. We have two differnet local hosts, so by default wont be able we req res data

//Setting up SQL, hide password properly 
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '*****',
    database: 'calendardb',
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // turns data into json

// insert information in to DB
app.post('/send',(req,res) =>{
    const userEvent = req.body.userEvent
    db.query('INSERT INTO calevent (userEvent) VALUES (?)', 
    userEvent, (err,result) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            res.send("Data send to DB")
        }
    }
    );
  });

//Getting data from DB
app.get("/getData",(req, res) =>{
    db.query("SELECT * FROM calevent", (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.send(result)
        }
    });
});

//Update data
app.put('/update', (res,req) => {
    //const newUserEvent = "test";
    //const id = 325;

    const newUserEvent = req.body.userEvent;
    const id = req.body.id;
    db.query("UPDATE calevent SET userEvent = ? WHERE id = ?", [newUserEvent, id],(err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
});


app.listen(3001, () =>{
    console.log('bonger');
});
```

The problem is that it is unable to get the variables from the front end and access it in the backend. if I uncomment the following: `//const newUserEvent = "test"; //const id = 325;`  and use that as my hardcoded user input, everything works fine, I can update my database.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

const CalendarApp = () => {
  var [selectedDate, newDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [event, newEvent] = useState("")
  const [userEvent, setUserEvent] = useState("")
  const [items, setItem] = useState([])
  const [userEventList, setUserEventList] = useState([])

  const [newUserEvent, setNewUserEvent] = useState("")


//Add event to DB
  const addUserEvent = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/send", {userEvent: userEvent,
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Data sent to DB")
    setUserEventList([...userEventList,{userEvent: userEvent,}])
  });
  };

  //Gets data from DB
  const getUserEvent = () =>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getData").then((response) => {
      setUserEventList(response.data)
    });
  };

  //Updates data chosen by user
  const updateUserEvent = (id) => {
    console.log(newUserEvent, id)
    Axios.put('http://localhost:3001/update', {newUserEvent:newUserEvent, id: id}).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

return(
      <div id="eventList">
        <h2>Event List</h2>
        <div className="List">
          {userEventList.map((val,key) => {
            return (
            <div>
              Event: {val.userEvent}, Key: {val.id}
              <div> 
                <input type="text" placeholder="Edit" onChange={(event) => {
                  setNewUserEvent(event.target.value) 
                  }}/>
                <button onClick={() => {updateUserEvent(val.id)}}>Update</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
)
```

the code `console.log(newUserEvent, id)` returns the correct updated user input and id number but for some reason when using axios.put it does not send it to the back end to be used there.

Comment: change `Axios.put('http://localhost:3001/update', {newUserEvent:newUserEvent, id: id})` to `Axios.put('http://localhost:3001/update', {userEvent:newUserEvent, id: id})` .  You are using wrong variable name while passing in the payload

Comment: This is not the issue.. and I'm still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userEvent' of undefined`

Comment: You have another issue in your code.Change this  `app.put('/update', (res,req) =>`  to `app.put('/update', (req,res) =>`. Request is the first argument and response is the second one.

Comment: Oh my, I've spend hours looking for the problem. Thank you so much, I can't believe I messed that up.